# How to rename a column without selecting other columns using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I want to know how to rename a column without renaming other columns in Linq
or adding other columns to the select statement.

```
 var sites = siteService.GetAllExpenses().Select(x => new { ExpenseId= x.Id, x.Expense});
```

I want to get a list  of expenses only renaming the Id field without renaming other fields and without including other columns in Select statement
Is that possible in LINQ?

Comment: does this query not work?

Comment: it works but only selects 2 columns i only want to rename one keep the others as it is

Comment: ah, I see.. But unfortunately you have to write all the columns...

Comment: You can use AutoMapper: http://automapper.org

Comment: I cannot use automapper we have dumped it , I looking for a way through LINQ

Comment: Using *rename* here is quite confusing. You want to project an object to another object with all but one identical property names. AutoMapper is *the* tool to do this. Just dumping it doesn't seem a balanced decision. If a tool doesn't always work for you, you can decide to use it where it *does* work.